# recursive value x$5 needs type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am getting error at this line

```
val Array(outputDirectory, Utils.IntParam(numTweetsToCollect),  Utils.IntParam(intervalSecs), Utils.IntParam(partitionsEachInterval)) =
      Utils.parseCommandLineWithTwitterCredentials(args)
```

- recursive value x$7 needs 
   type
- recursive value x$1 needs 
   type

what does this error meaning, please guide me how to resolve this error.

```
object Collect {
  private var numTweetsCollected = 0L
  private var partNum = 0
  private var gson = new Gson()

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Process program arguments and set properties
    if (args.length < 3) {
      System.err.println("Usage: " + this.getClass.getSimpleName +
        "<outputDirectory> <numTweetsToCollect> <intervalInSeconds> <partitionsEachInterval>")
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val Array(outputDirectory, Utils.IntParam(numTweetsToCollect),  Utils.IntParam(intervalSecs), Utils.IntParam(partitionsEachInterval)) =
      Utils.parseCommandLineWithTwitterCredentials(args)
    val outputDir = new File(outputDirectory.toString)
    if (outputDir.exists()) {
      System.err.println("ERROR - %s already exists: delete or specify another directory".format(
        outputDirectory))
      System.exit(1)
    }
    outputDir.mkdirs()

    println("Initializing Streaming Spark Context...")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(this.getClass.getSimpleName)
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(intervalSecs))

    val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Utils.getAuth)
      .map(gson.toJson(_))

    tweetStream.foreachRDD((rdd, time) => {
      val count = rdd.count()
      if (count > 0) {
        val outputRDD = rdd.repartition(partitionsEachInterval)
        outputRDD.saveAsTextFile(outputDirectory + "/tweets_" + time.milliseconds.toString)
        numTweetsCollected += count
        if (numTweetsCollected > numTweetsToCollect) {
          System.exit(0)
        }
      }
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `Utils.IntParam(..` from your pattern matched values. Extract the values, then parse them separately.