# "Recursive value X$3 needs type" in a fold operation even though the types are specified

Tags: scala, recursion

For the following `fold` invocation we can see that the types of each return value have been indicated:

(Note: the above content that is shown on the first "three" lines are actually all on one line #59 in the code)

```
val (nRows, dfsOut, dfOut): (Int,DataFrameMap, DataFrame) 
     = (1 to nLevels).foldLeft((0, dfsIn, dfIn)) {
          case ((nRowsPrior, dfsPrior, dfPrior), level) =>
     ..

   (nnRows, dfs, dfOut1)  // These return values are verified as correctly 
                          // matching the listed return types
}
```

But we have the following error:

```
Error:(59, 10) recursive value x$3 needs type
val (nRows, dfsOut, dfOut): (Int,DataFrameMap, DataFrame) = (1 to nLevels).foldLeft((0, dfsIn, dfIn)) { case ((nRowsPrior, dfsPrior, dfPrior), level) =>
```

Column `10` indicates the first entry `nRows`  which is set as follows:

```
 val nnRows = cntAccum.value.toInt
```

That is definitively an `Int` .. so it is unclear what is the root issue.

(fyi there is another similarly titled question - [recursive value x$5 needs type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772077/recursive-value-x5-needs-type) - but that question was doing strange things in the output parameters whereas mine is straightforward value assignments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inside a `print` statement:  the outer `foldLeft` argument was being referenced by accident instead of the inner loop argument

```
    info(s"$tag: ** ROWS ** ${props(OutputTag)} at ${props(OutputPath)} count=$nRows")
```

The `$nRows` is the *outer* scoped variable: this causes the recursion. The intention had been to reference `$nnRows`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an MCVE that does not have any dependencies:

```
trait DataFrameMap
trait DataFrame

val dfsIn: DataFrameMap = ???
val dfIn: DataFrame = ???
val nLevels: Int = 0

val (_, _) = (1, 2)
val (_, _) = (3, 4)
val (nRows, dfsOut, dfOut): (Int,DataFrameMap, DataFrame) = 
  (1 to nLevels).foldLeft((0, dfsIn, dfIn)) {
    case ((nRowsPrior, dfsPrior, dfPrior), level) =>
    
    val nnRows: Int = nRows
    val dfs: DataFrameMap = ???
    val dfOut1: DataFrame = ???

    (nnRows, dfs, dfOut1)
  }
```

it reproduces the error message exactly:

> error: recursive value x$3 needs type
>
> ```
> val (nRows, dfsOut, dfOut): (Int,DataFrameMap, DataFrame) =
>      ^
> ```

You must have used `nRows`, `dfsOut` or `dfOut` somewhere inside the body of `foldLeft`. This here compiles just fine:

```
trait DataFrameMap
trait DataFrame

val dfsIn: DataFrameMap = ???
val dfIn: DataFrame = ???
val nLevels: Int = 0

val (_, _) = (1, 2)
val (_, _) = (3, 4)
val (nRows, dfsOut, dfOut): (Int,DataFrameMap, DataFrame) = 
  (1 to nLevels).foldLeft((0, dfsIn, dfIn)) {
    case ((nRowsPrior, dfsPrior, dfPrior), level) =>
    
    val nnRows: Int = ???
    val dfs: DataFrameMap = ???
    val dfOut1: DataFrame = ???

    (nnRows, dfs, dfOut1)
  }
```

Fun fact: the `x$3` does not refer to `dfOut` (third component of the tuple), but rather to the entire tuple `(nRows, dfsOut, dfOut)` itself. This is why I had to add two `(_, _) = ...`'s before the `val (nRows, dfsOut, dfOut)` definition to get `x$3` instead of `x$1`.

Comment: I could not provide an MCVE due to privacy:  i have upvoted but will provide a separate answer for the root cause.

Comment: @javadba What privacy are you talking about? The above code snippet looks almost exactly like what you've already published anyway, but it's minimal & compilable. Since it's a **compilation** error, I'm not asking you to provide the full **runnable** code or real input data.